# How to get all minutes in a day?

Tags: c#, list, datetime

Is there a way to fill a List by all of minutes of a day? So, it must has 1440 (60 * 24) minutes as DateTime

> (14:37, 14:38, 14:39 etc..)

object.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var startTime = DateTime.Now.Date;
var minsOfDay = 
  Enumerable.Range(0, 1440).Select(i => startTime.AddMinutes(i)).ToList();
```

Comment: minsOfDay has 12h hour format. How can I make it 24h hour format? Thanks.

Comment: @team16sah : A DateTime doesn't have any format. It's a model of Time. The "format" comes from rendering to string. You need to check out the overloads of ToString and use a format string to display as you want. Perhaps `ToString("HH:mm")` might be of use?

Comment: I want to add some date in range 0 to 480, some different date in range 480 to 720 and another date in range 720 to 1440. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A longer, though easier to follow way:

```
var timeStart = DateTime.Now.Date;
var timeStop = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1);
var mins = new List<DateTime>();

while(timeStart < timeStop)
{
    mins.Add(timeStart);
    timeStart = timeStart.AddMinutes(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can use [`List<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) with [`AddMinutes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addminutes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods like;

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
DateTime midnight = DateTime.Today;
while (midnight < DateTime.Today.AddDays(1))
{
    list.Add(midnight.ToString("HH:mm"));
    midnight = midnight.AddMinutes(1);
}
foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/zrPTtw)</kbd>.

Comment: I need DateTime List. This is also can be useful. Thanks.

Comment: @team16sah `00:00, 00:01, 00:02`.. are not `DateTime`. Even `DateTime.Hour` and `DateTime.Minute` properties returns `int`. You can only get these values formatting your DateTime's with `.ToString()` method.. Even [spender's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21381185/447156) creates `List<DateTime>` but his result will be `27.01.2014 00:00:00`, `27.01.2014 00:00:01` etc..